# Foreach loop in foreach loop

Tags: c#, winforms, ef-code-first, entity

I am using  foreach loop to insert Values to database. I Have two students in  Class Six and six subjects for same class. When I run it, it upload only one subject for all students, i want to populate all subjects w.r.t students of class six... Where do I need iterarion in my code?

```
var source = context.Students.Include("ClassRoom").Where(x => x.ClassRoom.ClassName == searchLookUpEdit4.Text).ToList();
Evaluation ev = new Evaluation();
var source1 = context.Subjects.Include("ClassRoom").Where(x => x.ClassRoom.ClassName == searchLookUpEdit4.Text).ToList();

foreach (var stud in source)
{
    ev.StudentId = stud.Id;
    foreach (var sub in source1)
    {
        ev.SubjectId = sub.Id;
    }
    ev.TermId = Convert.ToInt32(searchLookUpEdit2.EditValue);
    ev.ObtainedMarks = 0;
    ev.Grades = "";
    ev.Remarks = "";
    context.Evaluations.Add(ev);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Just a tip, you should not copy paste code you do not understand. The code on top tells me you have some advanced knowledge of programming and the bottom part show you didn't grasp the basic yet.

Comment: A problem I see, it seems a student of course can have more than one subject, but your nested loop is re-assigning the next subject, you're not adding another subject, you're over-writing the previous one. `ev.SubjectId` maybe needs to be some form of a collection you add to.

Answer (score 1):

I think you inner `foreach` loop is not written correctly. Correcting the braces position will fix this issue.

Corrected Code:

```
var source = context.Students.Include("ClassRoom").Where(x => 

x.ClassRoom.ClassName == searchLookUpEdit4.Text).ToList();
Evaluation ev = new Evaluation();
var source1 = context.Subjects.Include("ClassRoom").Where(x => x.ClassRoom.ClassName == searchLookUpEdit4.Text).ToList();
    

foreach (var stud in source)
    {
        ev.StudentId = stud.Id;

        foreach (var sub in source1)
        {
            ev.SubjectId = sub.Id;
            ev.TermId = Convert.ToInt32(searchLookUpEdit2.EditValue);
            ev.ObtainedMarks = 0;
            ev.Grades = "";
            ev.Remarks = "";
            context.Evaluations.Add(ev);
            context.SaveChanges();
         }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant that you want one *evaluation* per combination of students and subjects. In that case you should do just that:

```
foreach (var stud in source)
{
    foreach (var sub in source1)
    {        
          var ev = new Evaluation();
          ev.StudentId = stud.Id;
          ev.SubjectId = sub.Id;
          ev.TermId = Convert.ToInt32(searchLookUpEdit2.EditValue);
          ev.ObtainedMarks = 0;
          ev.Grades = "";
          ev.Remarks = "";
          context.Evaluations.Add(ev);
          context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```